# is it possible to use DataLoadOptions with DBContext? How to filter with conditions in related entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I am using EF 5.0 and the DBContext and I would like to use eager loading to load related entities. I see that I could use the DataLoadOptions to load the related entities and filter which related entities are loaded.

[I this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37857/Optimizing-LINQ-Queries-using-DataLoadOptions)

In this example use DtaCOntext.LoadOPtions, but this is not avaliable in the DbCOntext, so I am wondering if really is possible to use DataLoadOptions with the DBCOntext or not.

Really what I want to do is to get the main entity which one or more related entities are equal to one or many conditions. I need also dynamic queries, because the user can stablish none, one or many of this conditions.

For example, if I have two entities, Persons and Orders. I would like for example all the persons that has pending pay one or more orders or in other cases persons with pending pay orders with date <= myDate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To achive your goal, You can use `Include` to load related entities
Another option is to configure `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

***Tip***

> Context will NOT do lazy loading if the property is not defined as
> virtual

Please read this: [Lazy Loading in Entity Framework](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx)